# android - Скрыть бэкграунд у TextView если он пуст

Tags: android, textview

Здравствуйте! Поставлена задача переопределить класс TextView так, чтобы если в нем не было текста делать прозрачным его бэкграунд. Как это сделать? Где найти TextView.java? Где в нем писать код и как потом в разметке использовать его?
Или может есть какой то другой виджет, который сам не показывает бэкграунд если текст пуст?
Нужно переопределить метод setText

Comment: Вроде как TextView не имеет бэкграунда и когда пуст и когда не пуст. Как сделать [кастомное View](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Comment: Найти TextView.java можно прямо в IDE, кликнув в редакторе кода на упоминании класса TextView и выбрав "Go to -> Declaration", при этом, если Sources Terget API проекта не были скачаны ранее вверху появится предложение скачать их, после чего вы увидите исходник класса.

Comment: @pavlofff, имеет. Иначе бы я не писал. У меня он в xml обьявляется. И если я передаю в него null, то остается padding

Comment: У меня ни эклипс и не студия. Я в телефоне

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно что то типа этого:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        if (getText().length() > 0){
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }else {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text, type);
        if (text == null || text.equals("")){
            setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }else {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Я протестил его при добавлении `TextView` из кода, думаю он должен так же работать если создавать его в разметке, если нет, то возможно нужно будет добавить еще файл атрибутов.

Comment: подскажите, что делает `invalidate();` ?

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, этот метод вызывает принудительную перерисовку View